# Product always goes OUT OF STOCK in magento 2 after inserting through REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, indexing, out-of-stock, product-reindexing

I have added product in my Magento 2 Store using REST API but it always goes out of stock like this.

[image]

But when i run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` the product will come in stock.

Any idea why is this or i have to run indexer re-index after every insertion of product.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: how are your indexers set? on save or on schedule?

Comment: @DianaBotean  on schedule

Answer (score 0):

Reindex implementation is required when the product has not been updated. This implementation has no effect on the functionality of your website
You can refer to here: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Updating-Stock-Status-Via-REST-API/m-p/449424#M10894